# I've had a fault on my broadband connection (now resolved) and my ISP has posted a diagnostic. Would it be OK to ask what it all means?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I'm not sure whether this would be a suitable question for SF or not.

My broadband failed a few days ago and has just been restored. My ISP posted the output from a diagnostic test as a response to the fault report and there are bits I don't understand.

Would it be OK to post the question on SF or would it be better asked somewhere else?

I did think Super User would be a good home for it at first, but as the problem was **not** with my equipment but with either the ISP's or the telecom's I thought it would be definitely off topic over there.

Comment: SU was suggested by someone else so I posted it there - http://superuser.com/questions/226093/what-does-this-diagnostic-output-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definitely http://superuser.com as that is not a sysadmin or server question.

Comment: I did think SU at first, but as the problem was **not** with my equipment but with either the ISP's or the telecom's I thought it would be definitely off topic over there.

Comment: @ChrisF, it's still a question from an "End User's point of view", so it definitely belongs on SU. Questions on SF should always come from a SysAdmin's point of view.

Comment: @Chris - point taken and indeed I did post on SU.